# defer fmt.print() LIFO to FIFO

Tags: go

I'm trying to print numbers from 1 to 5 which will achieve this following output.

The integers will be printed after the title: print no1, print no2, etc.

```
print no
print no
print no
print no
print no
1
2
3
4
5
```

I don't want to use array or slice because I don't want to have any more loop.

I'm using `defer` statement to do this:

```
func print(n int){
    for i:= 0 ; i < n; i++{
        fmt.Print("print no")
        defer fmt.Println(i+1)
    }
}
```

However, it gives me LIFO output:

```
print no
print no
print no
print no
print no
5
4
3
2
1
```

Is there a way to get FIFO output?

PS: What I'm actually trying to is to calculate the sum of int from console input and print it after.

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    allCalc (2)    //Two calculation
}

func calc(n int) int {
    var x int
    for i:= 0 ; i < n; i++{
        fmt.Print("print no")
        fmt.Println(i+1)
        var number int
        fmt.Print ("Insert number : ")
        fmt.Scan(&number)
        x += number
    }
    return x
}

func allCalc (n int){
    for i:= 0; i< n; i++{
        var n int
        fmt.Print("number to calculate : ")
        fmt.Scan(&n)
        x:= calc(n)
        defer fmt.Println(x) //printed after everthing is done
    }
}
```

Comment: No. From Go's spec: `Each time the "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function body is not executed.`, so `i+1` is getting evaluated but the `fmt.Println` is being executed in LIFO order. Well you could do some smart workarounds (tricks) to achieve FIFO.

Comment: @shmsr Yes, I aware of that, I'm thinking to use goroutine to controls the workflow so that print no5 is executed first, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: a trick: `defer fmt.Println(n - i)`

Comment: the concept is the same, isn't it? I think it's clearer if you present your actual problem, though.

Comment: @Glenio I have an idea: store the result in the channel buffer and handle FIFO in another goroutine. But it still needs a for loop, maybe you could have a look at `select for` and `channel`. I think the `for loop` couldn't be avoided.

Comment: @kkesley I have put my the similar problem on the post

Comment: @hyz can it uses the existing loop to do that?

Comment: @Glenio As far as I know, uses a slice and a for loop may be the easiest way to print the result FIFO. I don't understand why you want to avoid writing loop by hand.

Comment: @Glenio If you want to print the result after all the input finished, you need a place to store the result and print the result synchronously. Emm, Is there any way to improve memory and time performance?

Comment: You cannot change the order in which deferred functions execute. Print the numbers to a [buffer](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) as you're reading them, copy the buffer to stdout when you're done.